# Thread and slots QT

Tags: qt

I write a code like this:

myworker.h

```
class myworker: public QObject
{    
Q_OBJECT

private:
    int var;
public:
    myworker();
    ~myworker();

signals:
    void finished();

public slots:
    void chgvar();
    void doWork();

};
```

myworker.cpp

```
void myworker::doWork()
{
    qDebug() <<"doWork  "<<"Thread ID:  "<< QThread::currentThreadId()<< endl;
    while(1){
        switch (var)
        {
        case 1:
           emit finished();
        };
    }
}

myworker::myworker()
{
    var=0;
}

myworker::~myworker()
{

}

void myworker::chgvar()
{
    var =1;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QPushButton *var= new QPushButton("chg var");
    QPushButton *dowork= new QPushButton("do work");
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    QWidget *window     = new QWidget;
    layout->addWidget(var);
    layout->addWidget(dowork);

    window->setLayout(layout);

    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    myworker* work = new myworker();


    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), work , SLOT(dowork()));
    QObject::connect(var, SIGNAL(clicked()), work , SLOT(chgvar()));
    QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), work , SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));*/

    work ->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
    window->show()
    return a.exec();
}
```

When thread starts the slot dowork is called so it remains until the variable var is equal to 1. But when the button(var), that changed the value of var, is clicked the slot is not executed. Could someone tell if there are some errors?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I will recommend to use [QWaitCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) + QMutex instead of while(1). Forever loops, like `while(1)` or `for(;;)` very extremely used CPU time.

Comment: Just so you know in the future, don't remove the question by editing it just to say thanks.

Comment: yes I know was an error sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You moved worker to thread - good move.
The bad move is that `doWork()` has infinitive loop. Now what happens is:

1. Thread emits signal `started()`
2. Qt detects that worker is moved to other thread so queues execution of `doWork()` slots in event loop of your thread.
3. threads executes your slots `doWork()` and remains occupied forever since you have infinitive loop in `doWork()`.
4. now same sory is with `chgvar()` slot. Qt detects that destination object is in other thread so it queues execution of `chgvar()`
5. but now event loop never gets control so `chgvar()` is never called (it whaits until `doWork()` finishes its job)
6. so you have some sort of dead lock

Hot to fix it?
Change connection type:

```
QObject::connect(var, SIGNAL(clicked()), work , SLOT(chgvar()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Now other mutithreading issues are kicks in so you HAVE TO USE MUTEX to access `var` and you should make mark it as `volatile` so compiler will not optimize access to it and break code.

Comment: Better than `volatile` and a mutex, `QAtomicInt` should be used for the flag with this approach.

Comment: @MarekR The fix is the realization that event driven code must always be written in run-to-completion style, so endless or long-running operations are a no-no. The direct connection isn't a fix, it's a bad workaround for a deficient design. The event queue is already protected by a mutex, no need to add more mutexes to the mix for no good reason.

Comment: I agree that run-to-completion style is desired. In my answer explanations of problem is most important. There is more then one way to fix it (for example add `QApplication::processEvents();`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your loop never lets your thread enter the EventLoop, therefore use a timer:

```
myworker::myworker()
{
    var = 0;
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setIntervall(100);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(doWork()));
    timer->start();
}

void myworker::doWork()
{
    qDebug() <<"doWork  "<<"Thread ID:  "<< QThread::currentThreadId()<< endl;
    if(var == 1)
       emit finished();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);


     QPushButton *var= new QPushButton("chg var");
     QPushButton *dowork= new QPushButton("do work");
     QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

     QWidget *window     = new QWidget;
     layout->addWidget(var);
     layout->addWidget(dowork);

     window->setLayout(layout);

     QThread* thread = new QThread;
     myworker* work = new myworker();

     QObject::connect(var, SIGNAL(clicked()), work , SLOT(chgvar()));
     QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
     QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), work , SLOT(deleteLater()));
     QObject::connect(work , SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));*/

     work->moveToThread(thread);
     thread->start();
     window->show()
     return a.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should emit finished() signal when you actually finish the loop, i.e. when the value of `var` is equal to 1. I would write the function in the following way:

```
void myworker::doWork()
{
    qDebug() << "doWork  " << "Thread ID:  " << QThread::currentThreadId() << endl;
    while(!var){
        qDebug() << "Wait...";
    }
    emit finished();
}
```

Comment: This would still not make any difference as the while loop is blocking the event loop. The slot will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(1)` loop is blocking the event loop. The events are never processed. That is why your slot is never called. You should think about using a `QTimer`. Read [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. Your loop is not thread-safe. variable var should be set and checked with atomic operations. And should be volatile.
2. (As other users told) signals will not be emitted until you get thread workflow to event loop.

Comment: `var` is only manipulated from the worker thread, because the `chgvar` slot is called with queued signal. Or would be called, if the event loop was not blocked on the worker thread...